# Generating Hash Code for convert E-Mail Column into 15 digits for a column using Script Component in SSIS

Tags: c#-4.0, ssis

It is possible to generate hash code of 15 character for column using Script component or Derived Column in SSIS?

Comment: MD5 outputs 32 hex digits, or 16 chars but it would still be one too many for a a column length 15

Comment: ^^^ AS Jayvee says, unless you're rolling your own hash function in which yes, you could make your own 15 digit code. Script task yes, Derived Column No

Comment: I need a code for generate a hash code of 15 Digit number or character for a column  using Script Component in SSIS

Comment: As you've stated. The problem with your question is that you have not identified "what" hashing algorithm you need. There are many available each with different tradeoffs. You've identified it needs to generate a 15 digit value but I could supply a script that hashes every value to `100000000000000` That meets the stated criteria but clearly is not the desired result. Given input of "test@foo.com" it should produce 100000000000000 "foo@test.com" should produce 900000000000000 etc.